# Error running XUnit Test against SQL Server Data - Data discoverer specified for Tests.SqlServerDataAttribute on Tests.UnitTest1.Test1 does not exist

Tags: c#, xunit

I have an issue running some integration tests with xunit.  I have a process that inserts data to a MSSQL Database, then I want to run some tests over this data.

I am using .Net Core and xunit for the tests, and have used the sample from here https://github.com/xunit/samples.xunit/tree/main/SqlDataExample  to create these.

The error I am getting is Data discoverer specified for Tests.SqlServerDataAttribute on Tests.UnitTest1.Test1 does not exist.

Relevant code snippets below:

```
        [SqlServerData("ServerIp", "DbName", "DbUser","DbPwd", "SELECT name FROM Users")]
        public void Test1(string name)
        {
            Assert.Equal("T C One", name);
            
        }
```

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis;
using System.Globalization;
using System.Text;

namespace Tests
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Provides a data source for a data theory, with the data coming a Microsoft SQL Server.
    /// </summary>
    [AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Method, AllowMultiple = true, Inherited = true)]
    [SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Design", "CA1019:DefineAccessorsForAttributeArguments", Justification = "The values are available indirectly on the base class.")]
    [SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Performance", "CA1813:AvoidUnsealedAttributes", Justification = "This attribute is designed as an extensibility point.")]
    public class SqlServerDataAttribute : OleDbDataAttribute
    {
        const string sqlWithTrust =
            "Provider=SQLOLEDB; Data Source={0}; Initial Catalog={1}; Integrated Security=SSPI;";

        const string sqlWithUser =
            "Provider=SQLOLEDB; Data Source={0}; Initial Catalog={1}; User ID={2}; Password={3};";


        /// <summary>
        /// Creates a new instance of <see cref="SqlServerDataAttribute"/>, using a trusted connection.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="serverName">The server name of the Microsoft SQL Server</param>
        /// <param name="databaseName">The database name</param>
        /// <param name="selectStatement">The SQL SELECT statement to return the data for the data theory</param>
        public SqlServerDataAttribute(string serverName,
            string databaseName,
            string selectStatement)
            : base(String.Format(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, sqlWithTrust, serverName, databaseName), selectStatement)
        {
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Creates a new instance of <see cref="SqlServerDataAttribute"/>, using the provided username and password.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="serverName">The server name of the Microsoft SQL Server</param>
        /// <param name="databaseName">The database name</param>
        /// <param name="userName">The username for the server</param>
        /// <param name="password">The password for the server</param>
        /// <param name="selectStatement">The SQL SELECT statement to return the data for the data theory</param>
        public SqlServerDataAttribute(string serverName,
                                      string databaseName,
                                      string userName,
                                      string password,
                                      string selectStatement)
            : base(String.Format(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, sqlWithUser, serverName, databaseName, userName, password),
                   selectStatement)
        { }
    }
}
```

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data;
using System.Reflection;
using Xunit.Sdk;

namespace Tests
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Represents an implementation of <see cref="DataAttribute"/> which uses an
    /// instance of <see cref="IDataAdapter"/> to get the data for a <see cref="TheoryAttribute"/>
    /// decorated test method.
    /// </summary>
    [DataDiscoverer("DataAdapterDataAttributeDiscoverer", "Tests")]
    public abstract class DataAdapterDataAttribute : DataAttribute
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Gets the data adapter to be used to retrieve the test data.
        /// </summary>
        protected abstract IDataAdapter DataAdapter { get; }

        /// <summary>
        /// Returns <c>true</c> if the data attribute wants to enumerate data during discovery. By
        /// default, this attribute assumes that data enumeration is too expensive to do during
        /// discovery, and therefore defaults to <c>false</c>.
        /// </summary>
        public bool EnableDiscoveryEnumeration { get; set; }

        /// <inheritdoc/>
        public override IEnumerable<object[]> GetData(MethodInfo methodUnderTest)
        {
            DataSet dataSet = new DataSet();
            IDataAdapter adapter = DataAdapter;

            try
            {
                adapter.Fill(dataSet);

                foreach (DataRow row in dataSet.Tables[0].Rows)
                    yield return ConvertParameters(row.ItemArray);
            }
            finally
            {
                IDisposable disposable = adapter as IDisposable;
                if (disposable != null)
                    disposable.Dispose();
            }
        }

        object[] ConvertParameters(object[] values)
        {
            object[] result = new object[values.Length];

            for (int idx = 0; idx < values.Length; idx++)
                result[idx] = ConvertParameter(values[idx]);

            return result;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Converts a parameter to its destination parameter type, if necessary.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="parameter">The parameter value</param>
        /// <returns>The converted parameter value</returns>
        protected virtual object ConvertParameter(object parameter)
        {
            if (parameter is DBNull)
                return null;

            return parameter;
        }
    }
}
```

```
using Xunit.Abstractions;
using Xunit.Sdk;

namespace Tests
{
    public class DataAdapterDataAttributeDiscoverer : DataDiscoverer
    {
        public override bool SupportsDiscoveryEnumeration(IAttributeInfo dataAttribute, IMethodInfo testMethod)
            => dataAttribute.GetNamedArgument<bool>("EnableDiscoveryEnumeration");
    }
}
```

I have verified the connection string and the query against the database, and I have run SQL Profiler on the database when attempting to run the test but nothing is hitting the database.

Any idea what I am missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to find the issue.  You need a fully qualified type name on the DataDiscoverer:

```
[DataDiscoverer("Tests.DataAdapterDataAttributeDiscoverer", "Tests")]
```